# Sequalize js how to make multiple like condition with OR operation

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I have an array of words which I want to search into a database with `Sequalize`
`['orange', 'apple', 'apricot']`

How can I achieve a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE text LIKE '%orange%' OR text LIKE '%apple%' OR text LIKE '%apricot%'
```

with `Sequalize`  ?

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
const { Op } = require('Sequelize')

...

TableModel.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [{
      text: {
        [Op.iLike]: '%orange%'
      }
    }, {
      text: {
        [Op.iLike]: '%apple%'
      }
    }, {
      text: {
        [Op.iLike]: '%apricot%'
      }
    }]
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was missing the parenthesis `{` after bracket `[` `[Op.or]: [{`